# Can I force the resolution of a promise to await results in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

This question is somewhat academic in that I don't have a real *need* to do this.

I'm wondering if I can force the resolution of a promise into a returned value from a function such that the function callers **are not aware** that the functions contain promised async operations.

In .NET I can do things like this by using functions on `Task[]` or `return Task.Result` which causes the caller to await the completion of the task and callers won't know or care that the work has been done using tasks.

Comment: A code example would be nice.

Comment: In what context? Node or browser?

Comment: do you mean something like this pseudo code? `var foo = promise.resolve()`;

Comment: @Tivie In the browser, and yes, like `var foo = promise.resolve()` such that if the promise resolved a number foo is a number... with the intent to obfuscate from the callers that async work is happening.

Comment: @elclanrs I would provide a code sample but the issue I have is not knowing whether the coding of this is possible...

Comment: I'm inclined to say it isn't possible. The only way to make something async well... sync, is to wait for resolution. In the browser, as far as I know, you can't block script execution so...

Comment: If the calling function needs to wait for a response, the current best practice is to return a promise, alternatively take in a callback. A promise doesn't necesserarily mean that async work is being done though, it just means the function needs to wait for the result to take action on it. The promise could mean that you have a complex function with several different services performing calculations that need to complete for your function to return a value, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ES6 you can use a generator to make code like this. It essentially comes close to 'blocking' on the promise, so you have the appearance of a long-running method that just returns the value you want, but async/promises live under the covers.

```
let asyncTask = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    let delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(delay);
    }, delay);
  });

let makeMeLookSync = fn => {
  let iterator = fn();
  let loop = result => {
    !result.done && result.value.then(res =>
      loop(iterator.next(res)));
  };

  loop(iterator.next());
};

makeMeLookSync(function* () {
  let result = yield asyncTask();

  console.log(result);
});
```

More explanation and the source available here: http://www.tivix.com/blog/making-promises-in-a-synchronous-manner/

[Here is the code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=let%20asyncTask%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20delay%20%3D%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20100)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(delay)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20delay)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0Alet%20makeMeLookSync%20%3D%20fn%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20iterator%20%3D%20fn()%3B%0A%20%20let%20loop%20%3D%20result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20!result.done%20%26%26%20result.value.then(res%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20loop(iterator.next(res)))%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20loop(iterator.next())%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AmakeMeLookSync(function*%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20yield%20asyncTask()%3B%0A%0A%20%20console.log(result)%3B%0A%7D)%3B) compiled on Babeljs.io

Comment: (plus one) will something like this work on a browser context?

Comment: This will work in browsers that support generators, yes. Otherwise you can compile it down to ES5 with Babel and it will work pretty much anywhere.

Comment: That `Promise` is a generic function in this example so you'd need to provide that. Generators have a polyfill provided by Babel (an ES6 transpiler) https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#generators. It's all a little bleeding edge at the moment, but there is nothing that won't work in a browser in there.

Comment: This fails to work "*such that the function callers are not aware*". Please state that more clearly in your answer.

Comment: Edited a bit @Bergi feel free to take a stab if it's not crystal

Comment: Weird. I did not know JavaScript could do that.

Comment: "When the 'yield' keyword is encountered, the execution is suspended until a value (optional) is passed back" If this happens under the hood and the people consuming OP's library has no idea it's happening, couldn't  the code that consumes the library run into very unexpected results?

Comment: @Jan: The point is that this doesn't happen *under the hood*. The caller needs to know that it is calling into a generator, and put wrappers in the right place. The only advantage is that control structures can be written in a synchronous manner.